# serving same content from domain and subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain, server-setup

On apache server I set up a domain.com and a subdomain media.domain.com. I need the media subdomain to serve exact same files. I added inside sites-available/domain.com following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /data/web/domain.com
ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias media.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is how to prevent the subdomain from beeing crawled and considered as duplicate? Should I allow access only to files folder? Or what is the best practice in my case? My aim is to only serve files like images from subdomain. Thank you.

Comment: If you intend to serve only static content from the subdomain, why do you want the same files available on both domains?

Comment: I try to use CDN module (for drupal) so this module can rewrite all image paths to media.domain.com/. The page loag times should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice might well be to establish both services (domain and subdomain), and use mod_rewrite on your "unpreferred" choice to redirect all queries to your preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirects (as already suggested):

NameVirtualHost *:80

  ServerName domain.com
  DocumentRoot /data/web/domain.com


  ServerName alias.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / http://domain.com/

Alternatively, you do nothing on the server but signal search engines (e.g. via Google webmaster tools) that the two sites are an alias of each other.